# Reactor vs thread

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

My question is very simple in Java reactive programming

Thread Model:

1. User A (Lets say Thread 1), sends GET request to application.
2. Thread 1 will wait/blocked until it gets response from DB(IO request).
3. Once response received, block is removed and Thread_1 returns response to user.

Reactive Programming model:

1. User A (Lets say Thread 1), sends GET request to application.
2. In reactive thread_1 will have one call back to run. So it won't wait/blocked.

Question:

1. Who will run that call back? That is, which thread will run that call back?
2. What is event loop mechanism in reactor? Provide example in layman terms.
3. How to make use of multiple core CPU in reactive programming for NIO tasks?

Comment: you may want to improve the title of your question. Try it make it as clear as possible what your question is about. It will increase the chances of people viewing your question

Comment: Why would you want to make use of multiple cores for NIO tasks as you most likely wont gain any benefit, and only use more resources than needed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spring WebFlux has an event loop thread group which by default consists of as many threads as many CPU cores the machine running the application has. The callback is run by one of the threads from the group. If you use Spring WebFlux and WebClient (or any other reative data access library) then you get this multi-threaded behaviour out of the box.